# Co-Authoring for Office documents inside sharepoint document libraries, can we do it when opening the documents using desktop applications

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, co-authoring

One of the features end-users always use, is the co-authoring of Office documents mainly excel sheet, where they open the excel sheet inside the browser, and 2 or more users can edit the document at the same time. but i am not sure if we can still have the co-authoring capabilities, in those cases:-

1. if 2 users edit the excel sheet using their desktop excel applications?
2. one user edit the excel sheet using the browser while the other edit the document using the desktop app?

Now i tested the above 2 scenarios, and they did not work out-of-the-box, as when i try to edit the document using the second user, i will get the document as read-only and if i try to edit it, i will get an error message that the docuemnt is locked by the first user. so can i say that co-authoring for the documents inside sharepoint will only work if all users edit the excel sheet using the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you describe is avialable with Office 365 licenses. Excel/Word for Windows desktop, browser, Mac, phone, and tablet can be used by different people simultaneously to edit a document that resides in SharePoint Online or OneDrive.

Important to note is that the desktop app of Excel/Word, etc. must have the AutoSave slider turned on. Otherwise, co-authoring is not possible.

[image]

Everyone involved in co-authoring must have an Office 365 license.

Here is an excerpt from the [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104) page:

> Why am I getting the "File is locked" error? There are a handful of
>   reasons why this error can occur. The most common one is because
>   someone has opened the file with a version of Excel that doesn't
>   support co-authoring. If just one person does this, then everyone else
>   will get the "locked" error — even if everyone else is using a version
>   of Excel that does support co-authoring.
>
> Versions of Excel that support co-authoring:
>
> Excel for Office 365*
>
> Excel for Office 365 for Mac*
>
> Excel for the web
>
> Excel for Android
>
> Excel for iOS
>
> Excel Mobile
>
> - Co-authoring in this version requires the latest version of Excel for Office 365 installed, and requires you to sign in to Office with
>     an Office 365 subscription account. Please note that if you have a
>     work or school account, you might not have a version of Office that
>     supports co-authoring yet. This might be because your administrator
>     hasn’t provided the latest version to install.

Comment: but when i test editing a document (which is uploaded to a sharepoint online document library)  by 2 users, and those users edit the excel sheet using their desktop applications (Excel desktop application), the second user can only open the document as read-only and if the user tried to edit the document the user will get an error that the excel sheet is locked by the first users..so co-authoring did not work using excel desktop application... unlike editing the document using browser..

Comment: I added more detail to my answer. What license of Office are you using? Are all users on the same license?

Comment: thanks for the great help.. in my case i have Office 365 license + Excel 2016,, but if i edit a document (which is saved inside SP document library) using excel desktop app, i can not see any "auto save" slider nor i am able to co-authoring... any idea?

Comment: How can you have Office 365 AND Excel 2016? You cannot use co-authoring with Excel 2016. On Windows, you need an **up to date** Office 365 license using 1808 (Build 10730.20264) or later. If you or the others don't use the correct license, there will be no co-authoring.

Comment: i have office 365 license so i can login to sharepoint + office 365 + onedrive, etc... i also have office 2016 installed inside windows 7, and i login to my office 2016 using my office 365 username/password..

Comment: So, you are not using Office 365 as the license for your desktop client. Looks like you have an Office 365 license that does not include the desktop client. In that case you cannot co-author with Excel for desktop. Try with Excel in the browser instead of the desktop.

Comment: The license you need to have for this feature to work for your desktop apps is Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. If you look at the 'about' of Word and see Microsoft Office 2016 Professional it will not work and you will get the problem you describe

Answer (score 0):

Excel co-authoring for Desktop versions of **Excel** was released relatively recently, in 2017. [Related Article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/co-authoring-comes-to-excel-on-windows-desktops/42ea1b8e-6601-4e53-aeb7-381e50387125?page=5). For the very long time it was not supported.

As of today, this should be supported, but with several **important limitations** (credits to [Serge Tremblay](https://tremblayse.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/excel-co-authoring-requirements/)   ):

- You need an Office 365 subscription.
- You need the latest Office 365 version installed. Minimum version is 1808 [(Build 10730.20264)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/officeupdates/semi-annual-channel-2019#version-1808-january-8). (Important): **Credits to teylyn**. Thanks for finding the link and the exact version.
- You need to sign in to Office with your subscription account.
- You need to use Excel Workbooks in .xlsx, .xlsm, or .xlsb files. If your file isn’t in this format, open the file and then click File > Save As > Browse > Save as type. Change the format to Excel Workbook (*.xlsx). Please note that co-authoring does not support the Strict Open XML Spreadsheet format.
- All of the above should be true **both** for your and **your colleague** that is collaborating with you. It might be that your have the latest Office 365 Excel version while your college is still using Excel 2016. This is not supported.

To see the the type of update that your office subscription is on:

- Open Excel
- Go to Files
- Click on Account
- Look for Subcription product

Comment: Your information is outdated. Co-authoring has already been released to the semi-annual channel. It has been available since 1808 (Build 10730.20264) -- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/officeupdates/semi-annual-channel-2019#version-1808-january-8

Comment: thanks, @teylyn! that's a very useful information. I've updated the answers with credits to you.